# Can we reuse vouchers?

Tags: certification

So I received some voucher from my company and I received another voucher from a official Bootcamp Salesforce, I think I used the voucher of my company to pass to Administrator Certification. But the weird thing, I try to used the voucher of the bootcamp, but I'm receiving an error because he only works with de Admin Cert, I try in another account and works, but also, the voucher from my company works too and I believe that I used him to the Admin cert that I pass.
So I'm in doubt, because the two works, I used one, and I think it that was from my company. So my doubt is: We can reuse vouchers? Is there any where in webassessor that I can find which voucher I used?

Answer (score 0):

The best place to get an answer on this is to open a case in the Trailblazer community: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?support=home.